# Richardson's Law

Tags: energy

In 1929 Sir Owen Richardson received the Nobel prize making a connection of the negative radiation of metal due to the corpuscles coming out... how did he come from $s=AT^{1/2} e^{-b/T}$ as the law fully confirmed to 
$I=AT^{1/2}e^{10/\mathcal{k}T}$?

From what properties may I begin formulating a proof of my own? Don't want answers just need a place to look for my own curiosity.

Comment: Your question need some improvement and editing! In particular, you should define and explain the variables and the parameter in the equations and correct unphysical factors like exp(10/kT) in your second equation.

Answer (score -2):

A good start would be to read the Wikipedia article on "Thermionic emission". There you will also find additional references. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermionic_emission#Richardson.27s_law

Comment: The culture of Stack Exchange in general holds that link only answers are poor answers. We're not trying to assemble a link-farm here, we're trying to make the world a better place by providing good answers to good questions, and curating them into a helpfully ordered and rated whole.

Comment: @dmckee - Thank you for this information. Then it will probably be better to follow the copy and paste procedure from a link which seems to be a frequent practice here.

Comment: We have users who mostly cut and paste, and those answers are accepted as "real" answers, but if you look around you'll see that we also have more than a few genuine experts who write new content tailored to the question and that that kind of answer tends to get more votes.